# how to use PinStrap plugin for bootstrap site?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use [pinstrap plugin](http://bragthemes.com/theme/pinstrap-pinterest-meets-bootstrap/) for a site that images are uploaded by users and might exist in any size like Pinterset.

Now how can i use this plugin, i mean what HTML Structure needed, or whats css file or JS file add to project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a wordpress theme. You need to create a wordpress account integrate the theme then get all the necessary files like css js and html structure.